# Listening for array changes using MobX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

I just started learning MobX today and I want to listen for all array changes (insertion, deletion, etc) using MobX. An example would illustrate this better:

```
const TodoList = ({todos}) => (
    <ul>
        {todos.map(todo => <li key={todo.id}>
            <TodoContainer todo={todo}/>
        </li>)}
    </ul>
);

module.exports = @observer class TodoListContainer extends React.Component {
    static contextTypes = {
        todoStore: React.PropTypes.instanceOf(TodoStore),
    };

    render() {
        let todos = this.context.todoStore.getTodos();

        return <TodoList todos={todos}/>;
    }
}
```

If I add or remove an item from `todos`, the list isn't  updated. In order to make it update, I need to wrap `observer` around `TodoList`. The `@observer` on `TodoListContainer` doesn't do anything because I'm not accessing any observed properties. However, just for learning purposes, I want to use `observer` only on containers. I want to make the container rerender every time `todos` changes.

One way to do this is to do anything in `TodoListContainer` that iterates through all of `todos`. For example, in `TodoListContainer.render`, I can add `for (let todo of todos) {}` or `todos.forEach(_ => _)`. Is there a better way to do it? For example, in Ember Data, you can do `todos.[]` to represent listening to all changes in `todos`.

Comment: After a bit of benchmarking, I think the fastest hacky way to force a render is putting `todos.length` in `render`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The container component doesn't know exactly what data `TodoList` is accessing. In your example, it's looping through the array and accessing the `id` attribute of each todo object. MobX is smart at tracking changes. So if, for example, you change the id of the 3rd todo item: `todoStore.getTodos()[2].id = 3;`, MobX will rerender `TodoList` even though no item was added or removed from the array.

In general, I'd recommend adding `@observer` to all components and let MobX take care of tracking/rerendering.